# How do I put the inputs above the views?

Tags: sapui5

I was wondering is there any control that lets me put the inputs above the views. Right now the input is in the top left corner on the same level as the view.

I tried using tollbar, overflowtoolbar, horizontal, and vertical layout but that didn't work.

Here is my code

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="ariba.so.bulktransfer.controller.FirstPage"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:semantic="sap.f.semantic" xmlns:dnd="sap.ui.core.dnd">
    <semantic:SemanticPage id="SemanticPage" preserveHeaderStateOnScroll="false" showFooter="true">
        <semantic:titleHeading>
            <Title text="Transfer Content Items"/>
        </semantic:titleHeading>
        <semantic:content>
            <HBox renderType="Bare">
                <Input id="inactiveemployee" type="Text" placeholder="Enter Inactive Employee" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
                    valueHelpRequest="onInactiveEmployee"/>
                <mvc:XMLView id="availableContent" viewName="ariba.so.bulktransfer.view.AvailableContent"/>
                <VBox justifyContent="Center" class="sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd">
                    <Button class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" tooltip="Move to selected"
                        press="moveToSelectedProductsTable"/>
                    <Button icon="sap-icon://navigation-left-arrow" tooltip="Move to available" press="moveToAvailableProductsTable"/>
                </VBox>
                <Input id="activeemployee" type="Text" placeholder="Enter active Employee" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
                    valueHelpRequest="onActiveEmployee"/>
                <mvc:XMLView id="selectedContent" viewName="ariba.so.bulktransfer.view.SelectedContent"/>
            </HBox>
        </semantic:content>
        <semantic:footerCustomActions>
            <Button text="Transfer" press="onTransfer"/>
        </semantic:footerCustomActions>
    </semantic:SemanticPage>
</mvc:View>
```

I expect both inputs to be placed above the view and the views appear left to right with the button in between the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your Input and View in VBoxes and nest those VBoxes into a single HBox to achieve this order.

```
<HBox justifyContent="Center" class="sapUiTinyMarginBeginEnd">
    <VBox renderType="Bare">
        <Input id="inactiveemployee" type="Text" placeholder="Enter Inactive Employee" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
        valueHelpRequest="onInactiveEmployee"/>
        <mvc:XMLView id="availableContent" viewName="ariba.so.bulktransfer.view.AvailableContent"/>
    </VBox>
    <VBox renderType="Bare">
        <Button class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom" icon="sap-icon://navigation-right-arrow" tooltip="Move to selected"
        press="moveToSelectedProductsTable"/>
        <Button icon="sap-icon://navigation-left-arrow" tooltip="Move to available" press="moveToAvailableProductsTable"/>
    </VBox>
    <VBox renderType="Bare">
        <Input id="activeemployee" type="Text" placeholder="Enter active Employee" showValueHelp="true" valueHelpOnly="true"
        valueHelpRequest="onActiveEmployee"/>
        <mvc:XMLView id="selectedContent" viewName="ariba.so.bulktransfer.view.SelectedContent"/>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

Cheers